# Changing database from db.sqlite3 to postgresql_psycopg2 Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to change my database in Django REST framework from sqlite to postgresql and I get the following error.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-NvDkzG/psycopg2
```

> My current Django version is: **1.8.3**

Comment: Which operating system or distro are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the issue was due to crappy installation of psycopg2. Check out this [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20110305033324/http://goshawknest.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/how-to-install-psycopg2-under-virtualenv/) and it should solve your problem. Basically, you need to install `libpq-dev` and `python-dev` packages. You're either missing the required packages or have them installed in a weird location.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install two packages `libpq-dev` and `python-dev` on your machine(assuming a Linux machine).

Try the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
```

Comment: Apt-get is a debian/ubuntu thing, though. If you are using another OS, there might be similar packages that you can install instead.

Comment: Yep! I have written the ans assuming that its a Linux machine. Included the assumption in the ans. :)